# force iisexpress in visual studio to not use localhost

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

In mobile dev, mobile apps needs to calls IP not localhost.

To debug an asp.net webservice, and still use IIS EXPRESS, i updated the iis binding in applicationhost.config file so it uses a static IP instead of localhost. I added a new binding entry :

```
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:10600:192.168.1.10" />
```

This works ok when iis is started from the command line. But if iss express is started from visual studio (by pressing f5), VS overwrites the config by creating a new "site" in the file, without the additional binding to the static IP.

Any idea to fix this behavior ?

Comment: Isn't there an option for something like this on one of the project settings pages? I could be wrong, it's been a while since I looked, but I'm pretty sure I remember there being something like that.

Comment: I finally added a second binding using another port. With that one VS won't overwrite / create new sites.